# How to parse values in JSON file and return the values in a MessageBox?

Tags: json, vb.net, winforms, json.net

I'm developing a Windows form application using vb.net where a user input an ID in a textbox, then return a value in a MessageBox.

The problem I'm having right now is how to parse the value in the textbox, and then how to compare it with the existing values in the JSON file itself.

This is the code for Button class:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    myFiles = MyFileObjects.Deserialize(File.ReadAllText("[FilePath]"))
    Dim json = MyFileObjects.Serialize(myFiles)
    File.WriteAllText("[FilePath]", json)
End Sub
```

This is the module for Public Class:

```
Public Class MyFileObjects
    Public Class MyFile
        <JsonProperty("filename")>
        Public Property FileName As String
        <JsonProperty("title")>
        Public Property Title As String
        <JsonProperty("type")>
        Public Property Type As String
    End Class

    Public Shared Function Serialize(myFiles As List(Of MyFile)) As String
        Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myFiles)
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Deserialize(json As String) As List(Of MyFile)
        Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of MyFile))(json)
    End Function
End Class
```

This is for textboxes:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyValue = Keys.Enter Then
        Dim selectedItem = myFiles.Find(Function(f) f.FileName.Equals(TextBox1.Text))
        If selectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show(selectedItem.Title)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(myFiles.Select(Function(f) f.FileName).ToArray())
End Sub
```

This is the content of my JSON:

```
[
  {
    "filename": "123.xml",
    "title": "Hello",
    "type": "PU"
  },
  {
    "filename": "456.xml",
    "title": "World",
    "type": "PU"
  },
  {
    "filename": "258.xml",
    "title": "Test",
    "type": "PU"
  }
]
```

The user are expected to search for `datafilename` in the textbox field, and the display "title" in a MessageBox. Now I'm stuck on what to do next.

Comment: I'm planinng on adding an autocomplete to the textbox, but i dont know if that is possible if the values are stored in a json file instead of input the lists one by one manually at the autocomplete sources. Then, the user can pick one from a list which consists of "filename" values, and the match with "title" values. Lastly, the "title" values will show in a messagebox. Do you think it's possible to do this when I want to take the values from a json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JSON` is a List/Array of simple objects. It can be deserialized/serialized using a single Class object:
(A private Field, named **`myFiles`**, is used to contain the deserialized objects)

```
Private myFiles As List(Of MyFileObjects.MyFile)

Public Class MyFileObjects
    Public Class MyFile
        <JsonProperty("filename")>
        Public Property FileName As String
        <JsonProperty("Title")>
        Public Property Title As String
        <JsonProperty("type")>
        Public Property Type As String
    End Class

    Public Shared Function Serialize(myFiles As List(Of MyFile)) As String
        Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myFiles)
    End Function
    Public Shared Function Deserialize(json As String) As List(Of MyFile)
        Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of MyFile))(json)
    End Function
End Class
```

Note that I added:

- A [`<JsonProperty()>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm) attribute: this allows to modify the names of the class properties while preserving the names found in the original `JSON` when the List/Array is serialized. It's very useful when the `JSON` contains reserved keywords in the language (e.g., `operator`, `type` etc.)
- Two methods that allow to deserialize/serialize the `JSON` with a single call.

Deserialize the `JSON` to a **`List(Of MyFileObjects.MyFile`**):

```
myFiles = MyFileObjects.Deserialize(File.ReadAllText("[File Path]"))
```

Serialize the **`List(Of MyFileObjects.MyFile`**) back to a `JSON`:

```
Dim json = MyFileObjects.Serialize(myFiles)
```

Create the [AutoCompleteCustomSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletecustomsource) of a TextBox to enable its AutoComplete feature:
(The [`AutoCompleteMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode) and [`AutoCompleteSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource) properties can be pre-set in the Form's Designer)

```
TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(myFiles.Select(Function(f) f.FileName).ToArray())
```

Show a MessageBox when the User selects an Item using the AutoComplete feature:

Note that the AutoComplete will add a **`Key.Enter`** to the selected text when an item is chosen from the AutoComplete list. You don't need to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyValue = Keys.Enter Then
        Dim selectedItem = myFiles.Find(Function(f) f.FileName.Equals(TextBox1.Text))
        If selectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show(selectedItem.Title)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Add an Item to the List of objects, then serialize and save the `JSON`:

```
myFiles.Add(New MyFileObjects.MyFile() With {
    .FileName = "500.xml",
    .Title = "Title 500",
    .Type = "PU"
})

Dim json = MyFileObjects.Serialize(myFiles)
File.WriteAllText("[File Path]", json)
```

Complete code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private myFiles As List(Of MyFileObjects.MyFile)
    Private jsonPath As String = String.Empty

    Public Class MyFileObjects
        Public Class MyFile
            <JsonProperty("filename")>
            Public Property FileName As String
            <JsonProperty("Title")>
            Public Property Title As String
            <JsonProperty("type")>
            Public Property Type As String
        End Class

        Public Shared Function Serialize(myFiles As List(Of MyFile)) As String
            Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myFiles, Formatting.Indented)
        End Function

        Public Shared Function Deserialize(json As String) As List(Of MyFile)
            Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of MyFile))(json)
        End Function
    End Class

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        jsonPath = "[Insert your JSON Path here]"
        myFiles = LoadJSON(jsonPath)
        TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(myFiles.Select(Function(f) f.FileName).ToArray())
    End Sub

    Private Function LoadJSON(JSONPath As String) As List(Of MyFileObjects.MyFile)
        Return MyFileObjects.Deserialize(File.ReadAllText(JSONPath))
    End Function

    Private Sub SaveJSON(filePath As String, objects As List(Of MyFileObjects.MyFile))
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, MyFileObjects.Serialize(objects))
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyValue = Keys.Enter Then
            Dim selectedItem = myFiles.Find(Function(f) f.FileName.Equals(TextBox1.Text))
            If selectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
                MessageBox.Show(selectedItem.Title)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub buttonSaveJson_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonSaveJson.Click
    SaveJSON(jsonPath, myFiles)
End Sub
```

Comment: The error says here "e.KeyValue is not a member of system.eventargs". Does this mean I didnt include any namespaces element related to it?

Comment: You subscribed to the wrong event. The `TextBox.KeyDown` event provides `KeyEventArgs`, not `EventArgs`. Check your code.

Comment: I start to run it and input a letter in the TextBox then it shows this: _{"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source"} _

Comment: Post the code you're using now (updating your question). You didn't follow what I wrote here. If I don't see what your actual code is, I can't tell you what's wrong with it. In case you don't know how to update your question, it's the `edit` link just below it.

Comment: You haven't defined `myFiles` anywhere that I can see. I've never used the  `TextBox.TextChanged`. You definitely don't want to create a CustomSource in that event. I'll put together the different pieces in a new edit. Try to insert everything as described.

Comment: I thought that [TextBox.TextChanged] was for user input as it is different with what you gave [TextBox1_KeyDown].Thank you so much, Jimi. It works perfectly! T_T I've trying to solve these problem for week already. I appreciate your help a lot. Do you have any suggestion on how can I polish my vb programming skills in vb.net? I still have lots to learn.

Comment: Well, first of all, I'm glad you could put it to work. Then, you have StackOverflow. Read answers, post questions. Soon enough you'll know what's worth reading and asking.

Comment: If I were to get data from json in web api. Is it the same steps as what you have taught me?

Comment: Except the *get the JSON* part, yes, exactly the same. You'll of course need to adapt the class structure to the JSON the API returns. I doubt it's what you're showing here. There are on-line resource that can help with the class structure. [This one](https://jsonutils.com/) provides a VB.Net output. [This other](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) is a fake REST API to train your request.

Comment: is the Get JSON part, is the class structure part? The class with `Public Class MyFileObjects` name is it?

Comment: No. I'm referring to *If I were to get data from json in web api*. You're now reading the JSON from a text file. A REST, or generic API, request is of course different. But, once you have *acquired* the JSON, it's all the same.

Comment: Do I need to get a HTTP request in order for me to extract data from json web api?

Comment: It depends on the API you're calling. Some require that you POST a request for authentication, then receive a response or issue a GET request with the authorization token. Other just require a simple GET request, with or without credentials (these methods are specified by the API you're calling). The usual tools to send/receive from an API are HttpClient (preferable) or WebRequest.

Comment: I see, what about DB? Do I need one? I mean, to store the data of json in order the data to be in the web api.